# Using Excel formulas to create multiple rows of data from one row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2019

I am looking for a formula that takes the name and quantity of a table and itemizes it so the quantity amount matches the amount of rows the name appears.

An example being taking this table as input:

| Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| chips | 1 |
| soda | 2 |
| pizza | 1 |
| cookie | 3 |

And outputting this in the next sheet:

| Itemized |
| --- |
| chips |
| soda |
| soda |
| pizza |
| cookie |
| cookie |
| cookie |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work on all versions of Excel, but 2019 might well have a much simpler methods using new functions; this assumes that your initial array is in A1:B4.

First you need a helper column in A to do a COUNTIF of column B. Put this in A1 of Sheet2 and then drag it down:

```
=COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)
```

In B1 you'll need to put in the first value; either type it in or put in `=Sheet1!A1`.

Then in B2 you can use this:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(B1, Sheet1!$A$1:$B$11,2,0)=A1,INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11,MATCH(B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11,0)+1),B1)
```

This works by doing a vlookup of the row above and returning the Quantity. If the count in column A is less than the Quantity it repeats the value of B1 (and A2 will increase by 1). If the count is equal to the maximum is uses INDEX/MATCH to find the next Name on the list.

This is what my output looks like (with an extra Name and Quantity):
[image: screenshot of Excel showing formula in use and desired output]

Note that the Name and Quantity range is written in here as `Sheet1!$A1:$B11` but you can extend this as needed. It will break if you have anything with a quantity of 0 or if you have any items that appear more than once in the list. If either if these are a requirement then it might be possible to write a slightly different version

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, here is some code that will do it for you.

Press "ALT + F11" to open the code editor.

Right click VBAProject (in the code editor that pops up for your open workbook)

Select insert / New module

A new module pannel will pop up.

Paste this code below into it:

```
Sub CreateList()
    Dim StartingCell
    StartingCell = "A1"
    Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SelRange As range
 
    Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set SelRange = Selection

    Dim cel As range
    Dim selectedRange As range

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection
    Dim offs As Integer
    Dim rowloc
    Dim cellname
    Dim loopcount
    Dim totalcount
    Dim rowdata()
    Dim actrow
    offs = 1
    rowloc = 0
    totalcount = 0
    
    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        rowloc = rowloc + 1
        If rowloc = 2 Then
            rowloc = 0
            If cel.Value > 0 Then
                totalcount = totalcount + cel.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    actrow = 0
    ReDim rowdata(totalcount)
    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        rowloc = rowloc + 1
        If rowloc = 2 Then
            rowloc = 0
            loopcount = cel.Value
            If loopcount > 0 Then
                For i = 1 To loopcount
                    rowdata(actrow) = cellname
                    actrow = actrow + 1
                Next i
            End If
        Else
            cellname = cel.Value
        End If
    Next cel
    
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets().Add()
    NewSheet.Move After:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets().Count)
    NewSheet.range(StartingCell).Select
    For i = 0 To totalcount - 1
        ActiveCell.Value = rowdata(i)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Next i
        
    ActSheet.Select
    SelRange.Select
    MsgBox "New sheet created"
    
End Sub
```

Go back to your workbook.

Highlight what you need.

press "alt + F8" to get up the Macro list.

Select CreateList

Click the run button

A pop up will be displayed when the new sheet is created.

It must be two columns wide (as per your design), the text value in the first column and the quantity in the next column. You can technically have as many rows as you want, just highlight them all, and a new sheet will be created (every time you run the macro).

This should work OK with Zeros or negative numbers, in that they will be ignored.

You can change the cell in the line of script shown below (3rd line in) to change where the list starts being created (Just change A1 to the cell you want).

```
StartingCell = "A1"
```

Once created it can be copied and pasted if required with out any reliance on the initial list.

VBA is not my first scripting language, so it could probably be cleaner, but it is working code.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will do the trick. It uses the `FILTERXML` function to turn text into a range:

```
=FILTERXML("<Group><Element>"&  SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,REPT((A2:A5&"|"),B2:B5)),  LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,REPT((A2:A5&"|"),B2:B5)))-1),  "|",  "</Element><Element>")  &"</Element></Group>","/*/*")
```

MS says Excel 2019 had SPILL functionality. I don't remember it that way, but I think it must be because it had moved on to Excel 2021 before they rolled it out to us so I never noticed when what we had was still Excel 2019. `LET` was apparently not in 2019, so I did not put the `TEXTJOIN` uses into a formula-scoped name, but rather used the "repeat it as many times as you have to" approach.

`REPT` is used to repeat the text in column A's cells as many times as the value in the corresponding column B cells. `|` is placed between each so that odd coincidences in content does not lead to incorrect results later, but mostly so there's a known character to divide the string at. That internal array is used in `TEXTJOIN` to produce a string with all the required values and that is splitable. `LEFT` is then used to remove the extra "|" at the end of it.

Next `FILTERXML is set up with a starting string, this string with the "|" characters replaced with an appropriate XML tag pair, and an ending string, plus a simple XML path.

That shows all the pieces for a full use of the idea. But one could be slicker and replace the "|" characters with the XML tag pair and skip the `SUBSTITUTE` step:

```
=FILTERXML("<Group><Element>"&  LEFT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,REPT((A2:A5&"</Element><Element>"),B2:B5)),  LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,REPT((A2:A5&"</Element><Element>"),B2:B5)))-19)  &"</Element></Group>","/*/*")
```

The downside to `FILTERXML` is that this is not a function that works like `INDEX` in taking a range of any size at all and dealing with it. It has an internal limit, I believe at about 6,000+ characters for the array processed by `FILTERXML`. (`TEXTJOIN` also has this kind of limit.) So one would not want to needlessly add characters to the string. In fact, while I used  and  for clarity, people often use simple  and  instead.

But it still comes down to the fact that it cannot directly handle large ranges. So if you have perhaps 250 rows or so (700 "worked" for the example data set repeated to fill 700 rows in the sense that it did not USE all of them (see below) but did not fail for length, but longer entries in each with more repeats of them would affect things... so like they used to say, it worked for certain values of "worked") it could do nicely. Also, the internal (to the formula calculation process, but visible via stepping through with F9) array will cut off at precisely the length it can handle leading to some funny business vis-a-vis that last entry in it as it may end oddly. For example, an array that should look like `{"horsey"}` might end like so:  `{"hors` with attendant failure.

But if a short enough list and few enough repeats are required (as in average of 3 each, not 57 each), it could be quick and easy.

However, a VBA solution like `Netspud2K` gives is the gold standard for something like this. Even if it is not utterly optimized, it will be fast and not limited in the length of the result desired.